# Version of MQ in WAS 8.5.5

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I'm trying to migrate an EJB application from WAS 6 to WAS 8.5.5 and seems to not work entirely, doesn't respond correctly to the message-selector filter I'm using in ejb-jar.xml.

Can somebody tell  me the version of MQ server supported in WAS 8.5.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the MQ client (in the MQ Resource Adapter form) in WAS 8.5.5 is MQ 7.1. This page provides the list of the exact version of the client for each WAS level: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg21248089

The MQ server supported can be any currently supported version i.e. you can use MQ Server 8/7.5./7.1/7/6 etc with a MQ 7.1 client. However, there are features that might not be available if you are using a certain combination client/server.

For your issue it is probably best to post a new question with the actual error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Websphere MQ full installation, MQ 8.0 is already out but please check the following information about WAS 8.5 and MQ 7.5: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/prodconn_1.0.0/com.ibm.scenarios.wmqwasmig2v85.doc/topics/ts_mqv7cons.htm?lang=el
There are two alternatives depending on what you want to migrate before the other : MQ or WAS.